# Extracting text following a specific a-tag

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup, extract

i have a problem extracting text from a html-code with python. The code looks as followed:

```
<div class="...">
<br/><a href="link1.html" title="title1">anchor1</a>text1
<br/><a href="link2.html" title="title2">anchor2</a>important text to extract
<br/><a href="link3.html" title="title3">anchor3</a>text3
...
</div>
```

I want to extract only the text that follows one specific link. I know some words in the anchor2. Therefor it is not a problem extracting what is inbetween the a-tags with beautiful soup 4. But after searching around quite a bit, I found no solution to only extracting the text that follows my important a-tag.

I hope somebody has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the link, for example, by title and get the [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div class="...">
<br/><a href="link1.html" title="title1">anchor1</a>text1
<br/><a href="link2.html" title="title2">anchor2</a>important text to extract
<br/><a href="link3.html" title="title3">anchor3</a>text3
...
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find('a', title='title2').next_sibling
```

Prints:

```
important text to extract
```